# nuXmv syntax error when using variable instead of integer

Tags: syntax, model-checking, nuxmv

I have a model in muXmv, where I initialize with a range of values like -

> ```
> VAR 
>   x : 0..100;
> ASSIGN
>   init(x) := 10..50;
> ```

this works perfectly fine.

However, when I use variable instead of values,

> ```
> ASSIGN 
>   init(x) := LB..UB;
>
> DEFINE
>   LB := 10;
>   UB := 50;
> ```

it throw syntax error -

> line 14: at token "..": syntax error
>
> line 14: Parser error

Not sure where I am going wrong?

Also is there a better way to declare constants in nuxmv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **definition** is not necessarily a constant, it is just a name for an expression (whose value may change after each transition). **e.g.**

```
MODILE main()
VAR
    x : 0..100;
    y : 0..100;
DEFINE
    sum := x + y;

...
```

I don't know the reason why the *Grammar* of *NuSMV/nuXmv* specifically disallows writing an interval using a pair of identifiers instead of a pair of constants.

---

One alternative is:

```
MODULE main()
VAR
    x : 0..100;

ASSIGN
  init(x) := INTERVAL;

DEFINE
  INTERVAL := 10 .. 50;
```

Another alternative is to use the constraint-style approach:

```
MODULE main()
VAR
    x : 0..100;

DEFINE
    LB := 10;
    UB := 50;

INIT
    LB <= x & x <= UB;
```

---

If you really find yourself struggling with many constant values, one option is to write a generic *TEMPLATE* model and then use *regular expressions* + *scripting tools* to generate automatically the various *concrete models* you need.

Comment: the first solution still gives the same error, but the second alternative works.

Comment: will it be possible for you to explain the 3rd approach with example?

Comment: @SnehaSahu I have tested both examples with `NuSMv 2.6.0` and they both work.

Comment: I played around and found the causing factor for the problem. 
Whenever I use a flag in initialization which is an input to the process, then Variables are not working. I can share sample code, but in comment I cannot format

Comment: @SnehaSahu could you send it by email (look at profile)